# How to save a text box in my SQLite database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I would like to save text in my database, I can´t give it a **textvariable** as I used to do with an **entry** in order to save it in my database: This is my code

```
lbl_historial = LabelFrame(frame_historial, text='Historial', font='arial 12 bold')
lbl_historial.place(x=1, y=1, width='830', height='450')

myid=StringVar()

entry_idcard = Entry(lbl_historial, font='arial 12', justify='center', relief='sunken', bd=3, textvariable=myid)
entry_idcard.place(x=90, y=20, width='160', height='30')

text_historial = Text(lbl_historial)
text_historial.place(x=16, y=60, width='790', height='300')

btn_save = Button(lbl_historial, text='SAVE', width='9', height='2',
                                   activebackground='goldenrod',
                                   font='arial 12 bold', fg='white', relief='raised', bd=3, bg='green', command= lambda: [registrar()])
btn_save.place(x=200, y=373)

    def registrar():
      
        conn = sqlite3.connect("historial.db")
        c = conn.cursor()

        text = text_historial.get()
        datos = myid.get()

        if len(myid.get().strip()) == 0:
           messagebox.showerror('¡ERROR!', 'Enter a valid ID')
        else:
           c.execute("INSERT INTO history VALUES(?,?)", (datos, text))
           conn.commit()
           messagebox.showinfo("Registered")
```

Comment: You can use `text_historial.get("1.0", "end-1c")` to get the content of the `Text` widget.

Comment: @acw1668 It didn't work at first so I tried with this `text = text_historial.get('1.0', 'end')` and It's working fine. Thank you mate!

Comment: sqlite is irrelevant. You get the value of the textbox the same way no matter what you're planning on doing with it.

Comment: Guys, what I'm trying to do is a CRUD with an entry which will contains an idcard number and a text widget which will contain only text, I've solved the first part **ADD** which is saved succsefully in my database, but now I'm having a trouble to get it back to my text widget what I used to use was `text.set(usuario[1])` , but isnt working

Comment: Study the document for [`Text`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm) widget to understand how to use it.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the info, I'm gonna check out

Comment: Which text are you inserting to

Comment: @CoolCloud Hello buddy, It took some time but solved already thanks, I wonder if you could give me some ideas about how to restrict a Tkinter application to be used with only one computer per account, is it something related with IP/MAC address?,  my login form (username,  password) actually is working fine, but it would be great whether every account only work with one computer.